# LinearNDInterpolatorExtrapolate returns error with trivial example

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to use scipy's `LinearNDInterpolatorExtrapolate`.

The following minimal code should be as trivial as possible, yet it returns an error

```
from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator
points = [[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,0],[0,1,0],[.5,.5,1]]
values = [1,2,3,4,5]
interpolator = NearestNDInterpolator(points,values)
interpolator([.5,.5,.8])
```

returns

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

The error seems to come from line 81 of scipy.interpolate.ndgriddata [[source](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.3.0/scipy/interpolate/ndgriddata.py#L81)]. Unfortunately I could not chase the error further, as I don't understand what tree.query is returning.

Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, it seems like a problem with value type. Because first values of `points` and `values` are Python's integers, the rest are interpreted as integers.

The following fixes your code and returns a correct answer, which is `[5]`:

```python
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator
points = np.array([[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0],[0, 1, 0],[.5, .5, 1]])
values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
interpolator = NearestNDInterpolator(points, values)
interpolator(np.array([[.5, .5, .8]]))

>>> array([5])
```

Notice two things:

- I imported [`numpy`](https://www.numpy.org/) and used `np.array`. This is the preferable way to work with `scipy`, because `np.array`, albeit being static, is much faster comparing to python's `list` and provides a spectrum of mathematical operations.
- When calling `interpolator`, I used `[[...]]` instead of your `[...]`. Why? It highlights the fact that `NearestNDInterpolator` can interpolate values in multiple points.

Comment: I accepted your answer. What I find misleading, however is that `LinearNDInterpolator` accepts lists as inputs, while `NearestNDInterpolator` does not. However the error was more trivial than I was expecting. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the values without a list as a tuple of x-values

```
from scipy.interpolate import NearestNDInterpolator

points = [[0,0,0], [1,0,0], [1,1,0],[0,1,0],[.5,.5,1]]
values = [1,2,3,4,5]
interpolator = NearestNDInterpolator(points,values)
interpolator((.5,.5,.8))
# 5
```

If you want to stick to passing lists, you can unpack the list contents using `*` as

```
interpolator(*[.5,.5,.8])
```

For interpolating for more than one points, you can `map` the interpolator onto your list of points (tuples)

```
answer = list(map(interpolator, [(.5,.5,.8), (.05, 1.6, 2.9)]))
# [5, 5]
```

Comment: Is there a way to interpolate more than one point without a for loop? It's quite weird that `NearestNDInterpolator` uses a different syntax from `LinearNDInterpolator`

Comment: @LucaAmerio : Yes, I added to my answer

Answer (score 1):

Pass your input as arrays

```
interpolator = NearestNDInterpolator(np.array(points),np.array(
values))
```

You can even pass many points:

```
interpolator([np.array([.5,.5,.8]),np.array([1,1,2])])

>>>> array([5,5])
```